# Why does httpd seem to still be bound to an address when the service is supposedly stopped?

Tags: service, centos, port, apache2.2

This may be similar, but the reverse, of [another question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500105/why-is-pgsql-sometimes-not-listening-for-the-first-few-seconds-after-start-even).  In that question, the issue was the service was running but not yet listening on the port.  That I can understand, but this situation makes less sense to me: my service has already stopped, but is still listening.

Almost every time I go to restart my development Apache 2.2 service on my CentOS 6.4 box--if it's been some undefined amount of time or hits or something since the last restart--I have to do it twice, because it's still listening.  Thereafter it seems to work fine.

```
$ sudo service httpd-dev restart
[sudo] password for kev: 
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 192.168.99.44:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
$ sudo service httpd-dev restart
Stopping httpd: cat: /var/run/httpd/httpd-dev-80.pid: No such file or directory
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
                                                           [FAILED]
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
$ sudo service httpd-dev restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
```

How can this be?  Doesn't it stop listening the moment the service script shuts it down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I put a `sleep 1` line between `stop` and `start` in the `init.d` script, the problem goes away.  Perhaps the main httpd process has shut down but the child processes are still somehow listening for an extra moment.